# Invertibility of the symmteric matrix observed under least squaress solution

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

I am having trouble in proving the following statement

Let $X$ be a $K \times d$ matrix with rank $d$ and let $W$ be a diagonal matrix with $d$ *non-zero* **positive** elements on the diagonal, that is rank of $W$ is $d$ as well. Show that $X^\top W X$ is invertible. Assume we are working in the field of real numbers.

I am able to decompose $X$ in a SVD fashion of $X = U \Sigma V^\top$ to get
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{det}(X^\top W X)& = \mathrm{det}(V\Sigma^\top U^\top W U\Sigma V) \\
& = \mathrm{det}(\Sigma^\top U^\top W U \Sigma)
\end{align*}
But I am getting stuck after this. For $K=3$ and $d=2$, assuming first 2 elements of $W$ on the diagonal are non-zer0, i was able to show that the above quantity boils down to
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{det}(\Sigma^\top U^\top W U \Sigma) = \sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2(\lambda_1u_{11}^2 + \lambda_2 u_{12}^2)(\lambda_1u_{21}^2 +\lambda_2u_{22}^2) > 0,
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_i$ are the alements of the $W$ matrix. I would assume the statement to be true. Any help is appreciated as always. Thanks

Comment: The statement as it stands is false. Consider e.g. $K=5,\,d=2$,
$$
W=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1\\ &&-1\\ &&&0\\ &&&&0},\ X=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&0\\ 0&0\\ 1&0\\ 0&1}.
$$